# Store method not working using resource route

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am having trouble figuring out why my data is not being posted and stored in my database. I have used the resource routes for another form and it works fine, but here for some reason it won't work. Clicking submit just seems to refresh the page, no errors to work from!

So I have a form which gets the workout routines from a database, and on submission I want this to create a new Workout "session" in my database table (called "Workouts"). The form is this:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/')) }}

            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::text('workout_name', Input::old('workout_name'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Session Name')) }}
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::select('routines', $routine_names, null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
            </div>

                {{ Form::submit('Select Routine', array('class' => 'btn btn-success pull-right')) }}

            {{ Form::close() }}
```

In my HomeController I have this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Routine;
use App\Workout;

class HomeController extends Controller
{

public function index()
{
    $routines = Routine::all();
    $routine_names = Routine::lists('routine_name');

    return view('workout')->with(array('routines'=>$routines, 'routine_names'=>$routine_names));
}

public function store()
{

    $workout = new Workout;
    $workout->workout_name = Input::get('workout_name');
    $workout->save();

}
```

}

I have a model created for the Workout, and the route for this page is the following:

```
Route::resource('/', 'HomeController');
```

I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. The index method in my controller is working, as it is returning the correct view with the data I need. The form also looks OK I think, as I'm posting to the same page, but submitting doesn't seem to carry out the code I have in the store method of the HomeController.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: did you guys find any solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your route declaration from:

```
Route::resource('/', 'HomeController');
```

To something like this:

```
Route::resource('/workout', 'WorkoutController');
```

Comment: I've just been playing around, and think I can see the issue. The Workout page is the homepage, hence why I was using that routing. It seems the issue comes from the form URL ('url' => '/'), as when I submit it, checking the apache error log it posts the URL without the forward slash. If I put an absolute URL here it works fine! Is there a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the resources controller creator command of `php artisan` then all the specific routes are created for you. To see all listed routes  you can type , `php artisan routes`. This will show you RESTFUL routes even for your **POST** method .

And also even you did not created the resources controller and did made the routes with manual way then you can create ,

`Route::POST('/workout' , SomeController@post);`

I am trying to say , you have to use the different POST method for the form submission .

Hope this will solve your problem . Thanks.